# SQL Server から Null のレコードを取得時しても Null 参照エラーが起きないのはなぜ？

Tags: sql, sql-server, nullpointerexception

SQL ServerでNullのレコードを参照して値を取得しようとしてもエラーが起きません。
そういうものなのでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

例
【前提】

```
tableA(id, name)
tableB(id, name)
```

※tableAにはあって、tableBにはないidのレコードがあります

【実行するSQL】（外部結合）

```
select tableB.name from tableA left join tableB on tableA.id = tableB.id;
```

【結果】
tableBにないレコードのnameはnullで取得します。
→直観的に例外が発生するのかと思っていました。

(追記）
皆さんご回答ありがとうございます！
列がないのではなく列の各フィールドがnullになっているという点に気づいて、
自分の疑問は解消されました！
そしてnullを取得すること自体は問題がなく、クライアント側によってnullで何かしたら例外が発生するということ理解しました。

Comment: こちらも参考に https://www.engilaboo.com/sql-join/

Comment: SQL Serverは関係なくて、SQL Serverからデータを取得したクライアントプログラムについての質問でしょうか？ そうであれば、そのクライアントについて言及すべきです。

Comment: 疑問が解消した場合には質問に追記してしまうのではなく、役に立った回答に対して「コメント」を残すことを検討してください。(質問はあくまで "質問" の体裁を保つ必要があります)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Serverに限らず、そういうものです。

SQLのJOINは結合された表を作る処理と理解するといいかと思います。
ここで「表」といっているのは、行と列を持つものです。
LEFT JOINの場合、tableBに無い行に関しては、tableB用に用意された列が全てnullになっています。

「列がない」のではなく「列の値がnull」であるといった感じです。

ですので、tableB.nameという名前で指定して取得した列の値がnullですので、tableB.nameが返すのは例外ではなくnullとなるわけです。

Answer (score -1):

null の値をとってくるのは問題はありません。正常に実行できます
nullの変数からなにかをしようとすると、例外が出ます